# Is it known that $M=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2} \text{ and } N=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$,when we have a circle?

Tags: vector-analysis

There is the following graph in my notes:

[image]

and then there is the formula:

$$I=\oint _C \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}=2 \pi$$

So, at the formula of the Green theorem: $\displaystyle{M=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}} \text{ and } N=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$

Does this mean,that whenever we have a circle, $M$ and $N$ are given from the formulas above? Or is it just a specific case?

Also,according to my notes:

$$dx=dr \cos \theta -r \sin \theta d \theta$$
$$dy=dr \sin \theta+r \cos \theta d \theta$$

Why is it like that??

I thought that it would be:

$$dx=-r \sin \theta d \theta$$
$$dy=r \cos \theta d \theta$$

Comment: your question is not clear, what do you really ask? at the formula of the green theorem ... ?

Comment: Is it known that $\displaystyle{M=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}} \text{ and } N=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ when we have a circle or is it just a specific case?

Answer (score 2):

Let $C$ be any circle counter clockwise oriented and centered at the origin then set $C:h(t)=(rcos(t),rsin(t))$ for $t\in [0,2\pi]$ then

$$\int_C F dr=\int_0^{2\pi}F. h'(t) dt$$

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac {(-rsin(t),rcos(t))}{r^2cos^2(t)+r^2sin^2(t)}(-rsin(t),rcos(t))dt$$
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{r^2}{r^2}dt=2\pi$$

So, it is independent of the radius of the circle $r$.

**Note:** In our case, you can easily see that $M_y=N_x$ but you can not directly use the Green theorem  since $M_y,N_x$ is not defined on the origin. But if $C$ be any closed path which does not enclose the origin, then $$\oint_C F dr=\int\int_DN_x-M_y dA=0$$ by Green theorem.

Comment: A ok...so, each time when I have a circle and I want to calculate the integral I use $\displaystyle{M=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}} \text{ and } N=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ ?

Comment: @evinda: It depends on the function in that case $F=(M,N)$ where $M=\dfrac{-y}{x^2+y^2}$ ...

Comment: We only shows result of the integral does not depend the radius of the circle when $F=(M,N)$ ...

Comment: A ok..Thank you!!! I have also edited my original post and asked something about $dx \text{ and } dy$.. Have you any idea which of the two possible derivatives that I have written is right?

Comment: $x$ depends on $r,\theta$ then if $x=F(r,\theta)$ then $$dx=drF_r+d\theta F_{\theta}$$.

Comment: So,is the radius $r$ not a constant? Does it change?? Why it it like that??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14819/discussion-between-mesel-and-evinda).